How does Django BooleanField work with RadioSelect?
I have a model with a boolean
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    current_measures = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=_("Is there any control and safety measures?"),
        choices=BOOLEAN_CHOICE,
    )
    ...


I have a form that should set a value on this field using either true or false values.
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    current_measures = forms.BooleanField(
        widget=WidgetRadioSelectCustomAttrs(
            RADIO_WIDGET_ATTRS, choices=Risk.BOOLEAN_CHOICE
        ),
        label=_("Is there any control and safety measures?"),
        label_suffix="",
        required=True,
    )
    ...

Everything works fine until I set required=True on my form field and send the value "False" to validation method. In this case it raises ValidationError('Current measures is required')
As I found out while debuging, the issue is with validate method of forms.BooleanField.
At first it runs the method to_python, witch converts my value 'False' (type string) to False (type bool).
def to_python(self, value):
    """Return a Python boolean object."""
    # Explicitly check for the string 'False', which is what a hidden field
    # will submit for False. Also check for '0', since this is what
    # RadioSelect will provide. Because bool("True") == bool('1') == True,
    # we don't need to handle that explicitly.
    if isinstance(value, str) and value.lower() in ("false", "0"):
        value = False
    else:
        value = bool(value)
    return super().to_python(value)

Then the validate method of BooleanField class is being run.
def validate(self, value):
    if not value and self.required:
        raise ValidationError(self.error_messages["required"], code="required")

As you may see it checks not value (in my case it is False -> not False -> True) and self.required (in my case also True, as it is set in field's params). So True and True raises ValidationErorr even though it isn't really an error.
Can someone explain to me what i do wrong? Or is it a bug in Django?

required means that it should have a value that has a "truthiness" True, so required=True indeed will not work.

@willeM_VanOnsem what is a proper way to set form radio select to required, ie not be empty?


Can someone explain to me what i do wrong? Or is it a bug in Django?

No, required means the empty_value=… [Django-doc] should not be passed. For a BooleanField, the empty_value is False, so required=True, implies that you can not set it to the item corresponding to False.
A solution might be to work with a ChoiceField [Django-doc], and then map it to the corresponding boolean:
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # …
    current_measures = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=WidgetRadioSelectCustomAttrs(
            RADIO_WIDGET_ATTRS,
            choices=[(str(int(k)), v) for k, v in Risk.BOOLEAN_CHOICE],
        ),
        label=_('Is there any control and safety measures?'),
        label_suffix='',
        required=True,
    )

    def clean_current_measures(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['current_measures']
        return bool(int(data))

Thanks. You set me on a right track. I did't need to convert my values as Risk.BOOLEAN_CHOICE=((True, _("Yes")), (False, _("No"))). What I did after reading your suggestion: I changed BoolField -> ChoiceField and moved choices from widget to ChoiceField.
